# How to compare two datasets with Q-Q plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, distributions, ggplot2, qq-plot

As both a stats and R novice, I have been having a really difficult time trying to generate qqplots with an aspect ratio of 1:1. ggplot2 seems to offer far more control over plotting than the default R plotting packages, but I can't see how to do a qqplot in ggplot2 to compare two datasets.

So my question, what is the ggplot2 equivalent of something like:

```
qqplot(datset1,dataset2)
```

Comment: The ggplot2 docs might be helpful: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_qq.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just look at how `qqplot` works. So in R type:

```
R> qqplot
function (x, y, plot.it = TRUE, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), 
    ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), ...) 
{
    sx <- sort(x)
    sy <- sort(y)
    lenx <- length(sx)
    leny <- length(sy)
    if (leny < lenx) 
        sx <- approx(1L:lenx, sx, n = leny)$y
    if (leny > lenx) 
        sy <- approx(1L:leny, sy, n = lenx)$y
    if (plot.it) 
        plot(sx, sy, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
    invisible(list(x = sx, y = sy))
}
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

So to generate the plot we just have to get `sx` and `sy`, i.e:

```
x <- rnorm(10);y <- rnorm(20)

sx <- sort(x); sy <- sort(y)
lenx <- length(sx)
leny <- length(sy)
if (leny < lenx)sx <- approx(1L:lenx, sx, n = leny)$y
if (leny > lenx)sy <- approx(1L:leny, sy, n = lenx)$y

require(ggplot2)
g = ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=sx, y=sy))
g
```

[image: qqplot using ggplot2]

Comment: `ggplot2` does have a `stat_qq()`, is there some way to use that?  It seems to be designed to compare one vector to a theoretical distribution, I couldn't see how to use it to compare two different vectors.

Comment: You can actually get `qqplot()` to do all the `sort`/`length`/`approx` calculations for you:  `d <- as.data.frame(qqplot(x, y, plot.it=FALSE)); ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))`

Answer (score 9):

I use this when I also want a normal line.

`ggplot(data, aes(sample = data$column1)) + stat_qq(color="firebrick2", alpha=1) + geom_abline(intercept = mean(data$column1), slope = sd(data$column1))`

Answer (score 1):

If your original need is just to control the aspect ratio, here's one way to do that:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1500, 2)

myqq <- function(x, y, ...) {
  rg <- range(x, y, na.rm=T)
  qqplot(x, y, xlim=rg, ylim=rg, ...)
}

myqq(x, y)
```

[image: myqq plot]